# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf, which admin template to choose?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dashboard, spring-thymeleaf

I need to build an admin portal using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. I'm looking for a free admin template based on bootstrap 4.
I'm considering gentelella and adminlte

- https://adminlte.io/
- https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/
  Some advice?

I created pages and fragments, put all the libs in the appropriate folders on resouces .

With both solutions (gentlella and adminlte) the amount of files seems high to me

Comment: https://startbootstrap.com/theme/sb-admin-2